# android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible" doesn't work

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator

I would like to open the soft keyboard on when the Activity starts and I found that

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible"
```

doesn't work.

To make sure, I created a new project (the default "Hello world") and did the following:

1. added the windowSoftInputMode to the manifest.
2. After that didn't work, I added an EditView field to the layout
3. After that didn't work, I added

`getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE)`
 to the onCreate procedure.

I compiled it with Android2.3.3 and tried to run it on my Galaxy S2 device and the Android4 emulator
and still - no keyboard.

My manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity
        android:name=".HelloworldActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

My main.xml layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <requestFocus />

</EditText>
```

My code:

```
public class HelloworldActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);

    }
}
```

Comment: I think 'android:windowSoftInputMode' is 'activity' element/tag attribute.

Comment: You're right - I changed it. Still no keyboard.

Comment: what did you do? is it solved finally?

Comment: It was almost 8 years ago, but I see that checked Muky's answer. It was probably a bug in the specific keyboard I used

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you use the default android keyboard? If you do, try it on a different device, I know it has some issues

Comment: You're right. After I installed an external keyboard on my device, somehow my default KB was disappeared from the device settings. apparently it is a known issue and it also affected this. I Used a different device and its working. I still don't know why the emulator doesn't show the KB.

Answer (score 3):

Its simple thing.
I have done it and it works as your requirement.

1. Don't do anything with the manifest, leave it as it is while you creating the new new project.
2. Now define inputmanager.

   ```
   public static InputMethodManager imm;
   imm = (InputMethodManager)this.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
   ```
3. Now, here salary EditText is my EditText and i am showing the keyboard on the start of that activity.

   ```
   salaryEditText.setHint("select Salary/Wage");

   salaryEditText.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {new DecimalDigitsInputFilter(2)}); // Ignore this line

   if(!(imm==null))
   imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED,1);
   ```

That will help you to show the keyboard while activity start.

To Close keyboard on the activity finish see below code:

white this code while you finish the activity.

```
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(salaryEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Hope it will solve your issue. If not then let me know.

Enjoy. :)

Comment: @kenji I suggest to please follow accepted answer if this answer does not work for you.Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can force first focus on the `EditText` view by running:

```
final EditText edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
edit.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        edit.requestFocus();
    }
});
```

This should open the keyboard on activity start.

Comment: There is no need to create the unnecessary thread. Just see my answer for the solution.

Comment: post doesn't create a new thread, it adds a runnable to the view's queue, it's perfectly efficient.
I'd still go with my solution, seems more elegant to me.

Answer (score 1):

As I found [here](http://www.androidguys.com/2009/11/12/how-to-showhide-soft-keyboard-programmatically-dev-tips-tools/), you can show the keyboard when the activity starts by doing the following:

```
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    mgr.showSoftInput(editText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

I changed their sample code to have your EditText's ID, so that ought to work